# Suitable library for working with large data (> 10 GB) in R given enough memory (60 GB)

Tags: r, apache-spark, bigdata

**EDIT : This question is not a duplicate as only reading data is not a problem**

I want to do analysis on a csv file in R that is around 10 GB. I am working on a GCE virtual machine that has 60 GB memory.

I would like to know which library of R is suitable for reading and performing operations like filter, groupBy, colMeans etc. with large files

Which of the following should be the best choice (given that memory is not a constraint) -

1. Stick with `read.csv` and packages like `dplyr` or the apply family.
2. Use packages like `ff` or `bigmemory` for parallel processing.
3. Use RSpark on any other distributed computing framework.
4. Any other methodology that is perfectly suited for this.

Comment: @Roland Please remove the duplicate tag as I have reframed my question.

Comment: `fread` comes from the `data.table` package. This works well for big , but in memory, data aimed at group / aggregate calculations